# Failure to run Flex app on my phone

Tags: android, flex4.5

I found the same question asked but it was answered insufficiently from my n00b perspective.

The answers I find tell me to provide a different -target value. I don't know how to do this or if this is even possible running Flex 4.5 on OSX. If this is possible and the route to go, if someone could tell me how to do it, that would help.

Basically, I am running the demo exactly as described from the adobe site: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash-builder/articles/hello-world.html

It works fine in emulation on my desktop, but when I hook up my phone (LG-P509 aka Optimus T running Android 2.2) and hit run (the last step of the "Testing the app on an Android device" section) I get this error:

Error occurred while installing the application:
980 KB/s (6108444 bytes in 6.085s)
    pkg: /data/local/tmp/Runtime.apk
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_INVALID_APK]

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check to see if your mobile comes under certified devices in adobe. Only on Adobe certified devices AIR could be installed. You are getting that error because AIR could not be installed on your mobile. (And you need AIR to be installed to run flex app)

http://www.adobe.com/flashplatform/certified_devices/smartphones.html

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed [Adobe AIR Runtime](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.adobe.air) on the phone?